# VS2012 JavaScript IntelliSense for "var" not working?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, javascript-intellisense, resharper-7.1

According to the [MSDN documentation for the `<var>` XML Documentation Comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh542722.aspx), I should be able to decorate a variable so that the intellisense knows what type the variable is.

It's not working for me. Am I doing this wrong or does the feature not work in this context?

Here's an example where the intellisense works great for `bar`, but not for `foo`.

```
function demo() {
    var A = {
        "AA": function () {
            this.AAA = "1";
        },
        "AB": function () {
            this.ABA = 2;
        }
    };

    function asdf() {
        /// <var type="A">test</var>
        var foo;

        var bar = A;
    }
}
```

The intellisense for variable `bar` infers the type from assignment and displays correctly, showing `AA` and `AB`.

[image]

However, the intellisense for variable foo does not infer the type from the XML comment and does not show `AA` or `AB`.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Resharper?

Comment: I am using Resharper. I didn't try disabling it, yet. Never crossed my mind. Will try in the morning.

Comment: @SLaks that was it. Resharper not understanding the var comment. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resharper doesn't recognize Visual Studio's Javascript IntelliSense comments.

Disable it and it will work fine.

Comment: Posted a bug with ReSharper. They say it'll be fixed in 8.1 http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-368802